How to optimize assets like fences which curves involved without losing a lot of quality?
I was making a fence for an UE project but the triangle counts are too high even with decimating it only goes down till 200k triangles which is still a lot for an asset that there will be used multiple times in a scene. I also tried decimating with Planar -> Sharp but it also was only able to bring it down to ~500k without losing quality. I want to learn how to optimize assets like these.

You can control both resolutions, for the curves and for the profile curve. You'll have better control on the geometry than with a decimate, and it'll be faster to compute too. Any reason why you are not changing the curve resolutions ?

You either make it with geometry or with alpha and normal maps. If you make it out of geometry, this will need a lot of it no matter what you do. You cannot get good results with decimation here - it would be a better option to manually model it with the least amount of deliberate geometry that can hold the needed forms. Some sort of instancing may help with memory for something like this that only has a small unique part repeating a lot but how instances work in UE is off-topic here. Share the .blend file if you wish more specific help about optimal topology.

@Lutzi that's because I am a newbie and still in the beginner learning phase. I didn't even knew that was an option lol.

@MartynasŽiemys I would love to learn how to do that, it seems it would be better if I make it with alpha and normal maps. Can you point me to some tutorials/resources to get started? That would be very helpful. As for instancing in UE I can figure that out on my own. Thanks!

Curves have resolution, you can tweak it in the Data panel (green curve icon). For the profile, you probably want it to be as low as possible, 1 (square shape).
